# Insert chunk of text after cursor from vimscript

Tags: vim

I've thought it would be easier but I haven't managed to do it yet. I want to run a function that results in a specific chunk of text being inserted after the cursor (it is some text that I insert very often).

Once done I'd map a keystroke to such function. I can't use append() as I don't want to create a new line, just to append some text after the cursor, like the 'A' command does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mapping:

```
:nnoremap <F2> axxx<Esc>
```

That is, on <kbd>F2</kbd> run the command `a`, append text "xxx", simulate pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit append mode.

PS. Command `A` doesn't append after the cursor, it appends at the end of the line. Command `a` does append after the cursor.

You can also use abbreviation:

```
:iabbrev tx some long text
```

Every time you insert "tx" and press <kbd>Space</kbd> that "tx" is replaced by the text.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use

```
exe "normal! a".functionresult."\<esc>"
```

or instead of using `append()`, you can request the current line, change it at cursor position, and replace it.

```
let line = getline('.')
let pos = col('.')-1 " IIRC
let line = line[:pos-1] . functionresult. line[pos:]
call setline('.', line)
```

I'm likely wrong with column offsets (I've check the behaviour of the code), but this is the idea.

Note that depending on how your insertion is triggered, it may be simpler to just have an expression mapping

```
inoremap <silent> <expr> YOURTRIGGER <sid>the_function()
```